# Store a template type for later use

Tags: c++, templates, types, builder

I have 2 classes A and B

class A is a template class

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
  B getB(){return b;}
  ...
  B b;
}
```

class B is a normal class that holds a pointer to class A

```
class B
{
  ...
  template<typename T>
  A<T> getA(){ return std::any_cast<A<T>>(a); }

  template<typename T>
  setA(A<T> a){ m_a = a; }

  std::any m_a = nullptr;
}
```

but now when I want to go from A -> B -> A I have to specify twice the type

```
A<int>
  .doSomeARelatedStuff()
  .getB()
  .doSomeBRelatedStuff()
  .getA<int>()
  .doSomeMoreARelatedStuff();
```

is it possible to eliminate the second template parameter in 'getA()' call?
logically I believe it is since I am already holding that data in A..

I looked around but didn't find any useful solution to my issue..

I thought about turning B into a template but I really wish there was a different solution to this.

BTW I am building a builder mechanism if the context helps..

Comment: Is having a single class that has both methods an option? How about B inheriting A if that makes sense in your case?

Comment: `std::any_cast` is used to extract a value out of `std::any`, not to place it there. Its use in `setA` doesn't make sense; just to `m_a = a;`

Comment: What was `return A;` supposed to mean? It shouldn't compile.

Comment: The signature of `getA()` requires the caller to explicitly provide the type. C++ is a statically typed language, there's no way to declare a function whose return type magically changes at runtime depending on what code happened to have executed previously. There's no way to implement `getA` so that `b.getA()` returns `A<int>` sometimes and `A<double>` other times. For your proposed syntax to have a hope of working, I don't think you can avoid making `B` a template.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i mixed the set and get, fixed.